# sna: modification of the Dijkstra algorithm (shortest paths)

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph, sna

I've been using the function `shortest_paths` from the `igraph` package in order to calculate the shortest path between two links.

My `igraph` object contains the weighted links.

The integrated Dijkstra algorithm uses sums in order to express the shortest path.

How can I use the product instead of the sum?

Comment: please show your code it will be helping to recognize your question

Answer (score 3):

Log is a monotonically increasing function so the path that minimizes the product of the edge weights will also minimize the log of the product of the edge weights, or equivalently the sum of the log of the edge weights.  Therefore, you can just replace the edge weights with their log transformation and use the shortest path function.